# How to select the sum of multiple count() selections in JPQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql, ejbql

What's the equivalent JQPL statement of the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bar)
```

Comment: You might post what you tried and what error messages the Hibernate query parser showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the query you stated above along with [EntityManager's createNativeQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) function see example class below:

```
package facades;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class CustomFacade {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "TestJPQLPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public CustomFacade(){}

    /**
     * Gets the count of all records in tables foo and bar.
     * @return number of records as Long.
     */
    public Long getCountOfObjects(){    
        Query countQuery = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Foo) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bar))");
        Long count = (Long) countQuery.getSingleResult();        
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user953217 posted SQL and asked for the portable JPQL equivalent but this does not answer that question, sorry but -1 from me.