# Add result from two count queries using Hibernate HQL 5

Tags: hibernate, hql, jpql

Please tell me how to request a sum of two counts in HQL so Hibernate can parse and execute. Mysql accepts the following but I would like to avoid native SQL:

```
select ( (select count(id) from c_cat_map) + (select count(id) from c_acc_map) ) as c;
```

But the HQL parser from Hibernate 5.3.9 rejects this with:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree
```

This is the same question as this 2012 post but hibernate has changed a lot since then so forgive the near duplicate: [How to select the sum of multiple count() selections in JPQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328868/how-to-select-the-sum-of-multiple-count-selections-in-jpql)

Basically same as [How to write a query in hibernate for count(*) and + (addition)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49529470/how-to-write-a-query-in-hibernate-for-count-and-addition) but there is no HQL answer.

I am just trying to avoid two round-trips to the DB, would like to get the sum in one trip.  Maybe it's impossible without a native query?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like many SQL dialects, HQL has a mandatory `FROM` clause, but it offers no dummy or `DUAL` table out of the box. But in your case, you can work around this limitation by running the following query:

```
select count(id) + (select count(id) from c_acc_map) as c
from c_cat_map
```